# How to rectify Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException in windows phone 8 development?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to read the data from the json classes but I am getting the following Exception

> A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL
>   An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code
>   The program '[3048] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

My Json code is as shown

```
 string url="https://api.forecast.io/forecast/4b1ac2aa66db99adcf90578132b507d4/12.7342888,77.3791981";             
             WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

             webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
             webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url)); 






   private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
       MessageBox.Show(rootobject.currently.temperature.ToString("0"));
   }
```

I am getting that error @  **rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result);**,Please help me rectify the problem as I am new in this field.

My Json classes are as shown

> {"latitude":12.7342888,"longitude":77.3791981,"timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","offset":5.5,"currently":{"time":1397034594,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0091,"precipProbability":0.36,"precipType":"rain","temperature":92.91,"apparentTemperature":93.22,"dewPoint":61.18,"humidity":0.35,"windSpeed":1.91,"windBearing":340,"cloudCover":0.56,"pressure":1008.94,"ozone":265.48},"hourly":{"summary":"Light rain throughout the day.","icon":"rain","data":[{"time":1397032200,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.008,"precipProbability":0.29,"precipType":"rain","temperature":93.57,"apparentTemperature":94.22,"dewPoint":61.74,"humidity":0.35,"windSpeed":1.83,"windBearing":322,"cloudCover":0.57,"pressure":1009.22,"ozone":266.42},{"time":1397035800,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0097,"precipProbability":0.39,"precipType":"rain","temperature":92.57,"apparentTemperature":92.73,"dewPoint":60.9,"humidity":0.35,"windSpeed":2.02,"windBearing":349,"cloudCover":0.56,"pressure":1008.79,"ozone":265.01},{"time":1397039400,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0112,"precipProbability":0.47,"precipType":"rain","temperature":91.15,"apparentTemperature":90.84,"dewPoint":60.02,"humidity":0.35,"windSpeed":3.18,"windBearing":0,"cloudCover":0.62,"pressure":1008.53,"ozone":263.74},{"time":1397043000,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0125,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":89.52,"apparentTemperature":89.07,"dewPoint":59.72,"humidity":0.37,"windSpeed":4.35,"windBearing":1,"cloudCover":0.71,"pressure":1008.53,"ozone":262.71},{"time":1397046600,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0132,"precipProbability":0.57,"precipType":"rain","temperature":87.98,"apparentTemperature":87.8,"dewPoint":60.39,"humidity":0.4,"windSpeed":4.83,"windBearing":354,"cloudCover":0.78,"pressure":1008.89,"ozone":262.13},{"time":1397050200,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.013,"precipProbability":0.59,"precipType":"rain","temperature":86.3,"apparentTemperature":86.69,"dewPoint":61.72,"humidity":0.44,"windSpeed":4.92,"windBearing":339,"cloudCover":0.88,"pressure":1009.65,"ozone":262.01},{"time":1397053800,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0123,"precipProbability":0.59,"precipType":"rain","temperature":84.5,"apparentTemperature":85.99,"dewPoint":64.3,"humidity":0.51,"windSpeed":5.21,"windBearing":324,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1010.47,"ozone":262.09},{"time":1397057400,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0114,"precipProbability":0.57,"precipType":"rain","temperature":82.64,"apparentTemperature":84.55,"dewPoint":65.3,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":5.58,"windBearing":316,"cloudCover":0.99,"pressure":1011.17,"ozone":262.15},{"time":1397061000,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0108,"precipProbability":0.55,"precipType":"rain","temperature":80.76,"apparentTemperature":82.95,"dewPoint":66.24,"humidity":0.61,"windSpeed":5.79,"windBearing":313,"cloudCover":0.99,"pressure":1011.84,"ozone":262.21},{"time":1397064600,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0103,"precipProbability":0.54,"precipType":"rain","temperature":79.08,"apparentTemperature":79.08,"dewPoint":66.92,"humidity":0.66,"windSpeed":5.8,"windBearing":312,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1012.35,"ozone":262.42},{"time":1397068200,"summary":"Light Rain","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0092,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":77.77,"apparentTemperature":77.77,"dewPoint":67.25,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":5.59,"windBearing":313,"cloudCover":0.89,"pressure":1012.55,"ozone":262.93},{"time":1397071800,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0071,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":76.67,"apparentTemperature":76.67,"dewPoint":67.43,"humidity":0.73,"windSpeed":5.14,"windBearing":319,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1012.5,"ozone":263.79},{"time":1397075400,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.005,"precipProbability":0.48,"precipType":"rain","temperature":75.74,"apparentTemperature":75.74,"dewPoint":67.49,"humidity":0.76,"windSpeed":4.71,"windBearing":327,"cloudCover":0.62,"pressure":1012.27,"ozone":264.71},{"time":1397079000,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.0037,"precipProbability":0.37,"precipType":"rain","temperature":75.02,"apparentTemperature":75.02,"dewPoint":67.39,"humidity":0.77,"windSpeed":4.4,"windBearing":331,"cloudCover":0.59,"pressure":1012.1,"ozone":265.41},{"time":1397082600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.0031,"precipProbability":0.23,"precipType":"rain","temperature":74.56,"apparentTemperature":74.56,"dewPoint":67.11,"humidity":0.78,"windSpeed":4.13,"windBearing":332,"cloudCover":0.64,"pressure":1011.98,"ozone":265.97},{"time":1397086200,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.0026,"precipProbability":0.1,"precipType":"rain","temperature":74.58,"apparentTemperature":74.58,"dewPoint":66.8,"humidity":0.77,"windSpeed":3.82,"windBearing":332,"cloudCover":0.72,"pressure":1011.91,"ozone":266.47},{"time":1397089800,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-night","precipIntensity":0.002,"precipProbability":0.03,"precipType":"rain","temperature":75.35,"apparentTemperature":75.35,"dewPoint":66.54,"humidity":0.74,"windSpeed":3.42,"windBearing":335,"cloudCover":0.79,"pressure":1011.96,"ozone":266.95},{"time":1397093400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":76.99,"apparentTemperature":76.99,"dewPoint":66.17,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":2.92,"windBearing":340,"cloudCover":0.86,"pressure":1012.05,"ozone":267.4},{"time":1397097000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":79.29,"apparentTemperature":79.29,"dewPoint":65.63,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":2.35,"windBearing":347,"cloudCover":0.93,"pressure":1012.22,"ozone":267.82},{"time":1397100600,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":82.05,"apparentTemperature":83.83,"dewPoint":64.9,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":1.68,"windBearing":355,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1012.25,"ozone":268.2},{"time":1397104200,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipIntensity":0.001,"precipProbability":0.02,"precipType":"rain","temperature":85.14,"apparentTemperature":86.45,"dewPoint":63.9,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":0.87,"windBearing":4,"cloudCover":0.96,"pressure":1012.16,"ozone":268.6},{"time":1397107800,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","precipIntensity":0.0015,"precipProbability":0.06,"precipType":"rain","temperature":87.89,"apparentTemperature":88.68,"dewPoint":62.76,"humidity":0.43,"windSpeed":0.2,"windBearing":59,"cloudCover":0.95,"pressure":1011.92,"ozone":268.88},{"time":1397111400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0021,"precipProbability":0.1,"precipType":"rain","temperature":89.71,"apparentTemperature":90.19,"dewPoint":61.97,"humidity":0.4,"windSpeed":0.47,"windBearing":150,"cloudCover":0.93,"pressure":1011.46,"ozone":268.89},{"time":1397115000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0031,"precipProbability":0.18,"precipType":"rain","temperature":90.96,"apparentTemperature":91.39,"dewPoint":61.73,"humidity":0.38,"windSpeed":0.75,"windBearing":165,"cloudCover":0.9,"pressure":1010.66,"ozone":268.59},{"time":1397118600,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0043,"precipProbability":0.28,"precipType":"rain","temperature":91.51,"apparentTemperature":92.01,"dewPoint":61.82,"humidity":0.37,"windSpeed":0.84,"windBearing":166,"cloudCover":0.87,"pressure":1009.75,"ozone":268.27},{"time":1397122200,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0055,"precipProbability":0.38,"precipType":"rain","temperature":91.11,"apparentTemperature":91.66,"dewPoint":61.99,"humidity":0.38,"windSpeed":0.74,"windBearing":142,"cloudCover":0.86,"pressure":1009.11,"ozone":268.27},{"time":1397125800,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0065,"precipProbability":0.47,"precipType":"rain","temperature":89.88,"apparentTemperature":90.44,"dewPoint":62.14,"humidity":0.4,"windSpeed":1.01,"windBearing":93,"cloudCover":0.89,"pressure":1008.74,"ozone":268.51},{"time":1397129400,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0072,"precipProbability":0.53,"precipType":"rain","temperature":88.25,"apparentTemperature":88.85,"dewPoint":62.33,"humidity":0.42,"windSpeed":1.56,"windBearing":73,"cloudCover":0.89,"pressure":1008.68,"ozone":268.86},{"time":1397133000,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0077,"precipProbability":0.57,"precipType":"rain","temperature":86.45,"apparentTemperature":87.22,"dewPoint":62.69,"humidity":0.45,"windSpeed":1.6,"windBearing":67,"cloudCover":0.81,"pressure":1008.98,"ozone":269.22},{"time":1397136600,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0081,"precipProbability":0.59,"precipType":"rain","temperature":84.14,"apparentTemperature":85.21,"dewPoint":63.2,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":1.07,"windBearing":61,"cloudCover":0.66,"pressure":1009.72,"ozone":269.6},{"time":1397140200,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0082,"precipProbability":0.6,"precipType":"rain","temperature":81.74,"apparentTemperature":83.14,"dewPoint":63.65,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":0.4,"windBearing":49,"cloudCover":0.49,"pressure":1010.61,"ozone":270.07},{"time":1397143800,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0078,"precipProbability":0.56,"precipType":"rain","temperature":79.78,"apparentTemperature":79.78,"dewPoint":64.06,"humidity":0.59,"windSpeed":0.06,"windBearing":244,"cloudCover":0.38,"pressure":1011.38,"ozone":270.64},{"time":1397147400,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0072,"precipProbability":0.52,"precipType":"rain","temperature":78.21,"apparentTemperature":78.21,"dewPoint":64.47,"humidity":0.63,"windSpeed":0.44,"windBearing":204,"cloudCover":0.31,"pressure":1012.09,"ozone":271.35},{"time":1397151000,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0065,"precipProbability":0.46,"precipType":"rain","temperature":76.92,"apparentTemperature":76.92,"dewPoint":64.76,"humidity":0.66,"windSpeed":0.66,"windBearing":197,"cloudCover":0.25,"pressure":1012.54,"ozone":272.1},{"time":1397154600,"summary":"Drizzle","icon":"rain","precipIntensity":0.0057,"precipProbability":0.39,"precipType":"rain","temperature":75.85,"apparentTemperature":75.85,"dewPoint":64.86,"humidity":0.69,"windSpeed":0.45,"windBearing":205,"cloudCover":0.18,"pressure":1012.6,"ozone":272.8},{"time":1397158200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0.0046,"precipProbability":0.3,"precipType":"rain","temperature":74.89,"apparentTemperature":74.89,"dewPoint":64.88,"humidity":0.71,"windSpeed":0.37,"windBearing":335,"cloudCover":0.09,"pressure":1012.19,"ozone":273.47},{"time":1397161800,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0.0034,"precipProbability":0.2,"precipType":"rain","temperature":73.96,"apparentTemperature":73.96,"dewPoint":64.86,"humidity":0.73,"windSpeed":1.03,"windBearing":354,"cloudCover":0.02,"pressure":1011.64,"ozone":274.13},{"time":1397165400,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0.0024,"precipProbability":0.12,"precipType":"rain","temperature":72.92,"apparentTemperature":72.92,"dewPoint":64.75,"humidity":0.76,"windSpeed":1.07,"windBearing":355,"cloudCover":0,"pressure":1011.35,"ozone":274.78},{"time":1397169000,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0.0017,"precipProbability":0.06,"precipType":"rain","temperature":71.7,"apparentTemperature":71.7,"dewPoint":64.45,"humidity":0.78,"windSpeed":0.48,"windBearing":353,"cloudCover":0.02,"pressure":1011.19,"ozone":275.36},{"time":1397172600,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0.0012,"precipProbability":0.01,"precipType":"rain","temperature":71.22,"apparentTemperature":71.22,"dewPoint":64.26,"humidity":0.79,"windSpeed":0.35,"windBearing":190,"cloudCover":0.07,"pressure":1011.17,"ozone":276.03},{"time":1397176200,"summary":"Clear","icon":"clear-night","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":72.46,"apparentTemperature":72.46,"dewPoint":64.48,"humidity":0.76,"windSpeed":1.12,"windBearing":190,"cloudCover":0.16,"pressure":1011.41,"ozone":277},{"time":1397179800,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":75.53,"apparentTemperature":75.53,"dewPoint":64.87,"humidity":0.7,"windSpeed":2.06,"windBearing":195,"cloudCover":0.3,"pressure":1011.85,"ozone":278.24},{"time":1397183400,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0005,"precipProbability":0.02,"precipType":"rain","temperature":79.56,"apparentTemperature":79.56,"dewPoint":65.02,"humidity":0.61,"windSpeed":2.88,"windBearing":196,"cloudCover":0.44,"pressure":1012.12,"ozone":279.6},{"time":1397187000,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0007,"precipProbability":0.04,"precipType":"rain","temperature":83.9,"apparentTemperature":85.61,"dewPoint":64.82,"humidity":0.53,"windSpeed":3.18,"windBearing":195,"cloudCover":0.51,"pressure":1012.17,"ozone":281.03},{"time":1397190600,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.001,"precipProbability":0.07,"precipType":"rain","temperature":88.77,"apparentTemperature":90.35,"dewPoint":64.34,"humidity":0.45,"windSpeed":2.95,"windBearing":193,"cloudCover":0.5,"pressure":1011.98,"ozone":282.7},{"time":1397194200,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0014,"precipProbability":0.09,"precipType":"rain","temperature":92.72,"apparentTemperature":94.04,"dewPoint":63.21,"humidity":0.38,"windSpeed":2.42,"windBearing":188,"cloudCover":0.49,"pressure":1011.59,"ozone":284.11},{"time":1397197800,"summary":"Partly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0018,"precipProbability":0.11,"precipType":"rain","temperature":94.2,"apparentTemperature":94.94,"dewPoint":61.8,"humidity":0.34,"windSpeed":1.86,"windBearing":170,"cloudCover":0.55,"pressure":1010.94,"ozone":284.69},{"time":1397201400,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0023,"precipProbability":0.12,"precipType":"rain","temperature":93.46,"apparentTemperature":93.47,"dewPoint":60.4,"humidity":0.33,"windSpeed":1.68,"windBearing":126,"cloudCover":0.69,"pressure":1009.91,"ozone":284.58},{"time":1397205000,"summary":"Mostly Cloudy","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","precipIntensity":0.0031,"precipProbability":0.13,"precipType":"rain","temperature":91.75,"apparentTemperature":91.26,"dewPoint":59.48,"humidity":0.34,"windSpeed":2.5,"windBearing":94,"cloudCover":0.82,"pressure":1008.97,"ozone":283.97}]},"daily":{"summary":"Light rain today through Sunday, with temperatures rising to 98°F on Wednesday.","icon":"rain","data":[{"time":1396981800,"summary":"Light rain starting in the afternoon.","icon":"rain","sunriseTime":1397004180,"sunsetTime":1397048608,"moonPhase":0.33,"precipIntensity":0.0074,"precipIntensityMax":0.0132,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397046600,"precipProbability":0.8,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":77.15,"temperatureMinTime":1396999800,"temperatureMax":94.32,"temperatureMaxTime":1397028600,"apparentTemperatureMin":77.15,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1396999800,"apparentTemperatureMax":95.13,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397028600,"dewPoint":63.19,"humidity":0.5,"windSpeed":3.64,"windBearing":292,"cloudCover":0.86,"pressure":1010.64,"ozone":266.96},{"time":1397068200,"summary":"Drizzle starting in the afternoon.","icon":"rain","sunriseTime":1397090543,"sunsetTime":1397135013,"moonPhase":0.36,"precipIntensity":0.0047,"precipIntensityMax":0.0092,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397068200,"precipProbability":0.6,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":74.56,"temperatureMinTime":1397082600,"temperatureMax":91.51,"temperatureMaxTime":1397118600,"apparentTemperatureMin":74.56,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397082600,"apparentTemperatureMax":92.01,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397118600,"dewPoint":64.51,"humidity":0.57,"windSpeed":1.42,"windBearing":338,"cloudCover":0.75,"pressure":1011.23,"ozone":267.98},{"time":1397154600,"summary":"Light rain in the evening.","icon":"rain","sunriseTime":1397176906,"sunsetTime":1397221417,"moonPhase":0.39,"precipIntensity":0.0048,"precipIntensityMax":0.0147,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397230200,"precipProbability":0.39,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":71.22,"temperatureMinTime":1397172600,"temperatureMax":94.2,"temperatureMaxTime":1397197800,"apparentTemperatureMin":71.22,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397172600,"apparentTemperatureMax":94.94,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397197800,"dewPoint":63.28,"humidity":0.56,"windSpeed":1.51,"windBearing":140,"cloudCover":0.55,"pressure":1010.61,"ozone":279.1},{"time":1397241000,"summary":"Drizzle overnight.","icon":"rain","sunriseTime":1397263269,"sunsetTime":1397307822,"moonPhase":0.43,"precipIntensity":0.0022,"precipIntensityMax":0.0069,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397323800,"precipProbability":0.47,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":71.47,"temperatureMinTime":1397259000,"temperatureMax":93.66,"temperatureMaxTime":1397287800,"apparentTemperatureMin":71.47,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397259000,"apparentTemperatureMax":93.74,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397287800,"dewPoint":63.3,"humidity":0.54,"windSpeed":1.48,"windBearing":171,"cloudCover":0.53,"pressure":1009.74,"ozone":279.01},{"time":1397327400,"summary":"Mostly cloudy starting in the afternoon.","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","sunriseTime":1397349633,"sunsetTime":1397394227,"moonPhase":0.46,"precipIntensity":0.0014,"precipIntensityMax":0.0066,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397327400,"precipProbability":0.44,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":74.8,"temperatureMinTime":1397345400,"temperatureMax":95.6,"temperatureMaxTime":1397374200,"apparentTemperatureMin":74.8,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397345400,"apparentTemperatureMax":95.56,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397374200,"dewPoint":62.74,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":2.6,"windBearing":144,"cloudCover":0.54,"pressure":1009.92,"ozone":275.42},{"time":1397413800,"summary":"Partly cloudy starting in the afternoon.","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","sunriseTime":1397435998,"sunsetTime":1397480632,"moonPhase":0.5,"precipIntensity":0.0013,"precipIntensityMax":0.0021,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397413800,"precipProbability":0.14,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":75.12,"temperatureMinTime":1397431800,"temperatureMax":95.21,"temperatureMaxTime":1397464200,"apparentTemperatureMin":75.12,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397431800,"apparentTemperatureMax":94.98,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397464200,"dewPoint":62.66,"humidity":0.49,"windSpeed":2.74,"windBearing":150,"cloudCover":0.3,"pressure":1010.7,"ozone":273.18},{"time":1397500200,"summary":"Mostly cloudy starting in the afternoon.","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","sunriseTime":1397522363,"sunsetTime":1397567038,"moonPhase":0.53,"precipIntensity":0.0006,"precipIntensityMax":0.0013,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397500200,"precipProbability":0.1,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":74.65,"temperatureMinTime":1397518200,"temperatureMax":97.78,"temperatureMaxTime":1397550600,"apparentTemperatureMin":74.65,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397518200,"apparentTemperatureMax":97.4,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397550600,"dewPoint":61.19,"humidity":0.46,"windSpeed":1.22,"windBearing":193,"cloudCover":0.27,"pressure":1010.14,"ozone":269.12},{"time":1397586600,"summary":"Mostly cloudy starting in the afternoon.","icon":"partly-cloudy-day","sunriseTime":1397608728,"sunsetTime":1397653444,"moonPhase":0.56,"precipIntensity":0.0007,"precipIntensityMax":0.0016,"precipIntensityMaxTime":1397669400,"precipProbability":0.17,"precipType":"rain","temperatureMin":75.21,"temperatureMinTime":1397604600,"temperatureMax":98.48,"temperatureMaxTime":1397637000,"apparentTemperatureMin":75.21,"apparentTemperatureMinTime":1397604600,"apparentTemperatureMax":97.66,"apparentTemperatureMaxTime":1397637000,"dewPoint":60.81,"humidity":0.44,"windSpeed":1.44,"windBearing":239,"cloudCover":0.32,"pressure":1008.8,"ozone":266.18}]},"flags":{"sources":["isd","madis","fnmoc","cmc","gfs"],"isd-stations":["427056-99999","432890-99999","432910-99999","432950-99999","432960-99999"],"madis-stations":["E0882","VOBL"],"units":"us"}}

Answer (score 1):

You have not shared the RootObject class members.

This is how you need to do it

```
public class Currently
{

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipIntensity")]
    public double PrecipIntensity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipProbability")]
    public double PrecipProbability { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipType")]
    public string PrecipType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperature")]
    public double Temperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperature")]
    public double ApparentTemperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dewPoint")]
    public double DewPoint { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("humidity")]
    public double Humidity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windSpeed")]
    public double WindSpeed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windBearing")]
    public int WindBearing { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cloudCover")]
    public double CloudCover { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pressure")]
    public double Pressure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ozone")]
    public double Ozone { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipIntensity")]
    public double PrecipIntensity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipProbability")]
    public double PrecipProbability { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipType")]
    public string PrecipType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperature")]
    public double Temperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperature")]
    public double ApparentTemperature { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dewPoint")]
    public double DewPoint { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("humidity")]
    public double Humidity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windSpeed")]
    public double WindSpeed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windBearing")]
    public int WindBearing { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cloudCover")]
    public double CloudCover { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pressure")]
    public double Pressure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ozone")]
    public double Ozone { get; set; }
}

public class Hourly
{

    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunriseTime")]
    public int SunriseTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunsetTime")]
    public int SunsetTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("moonPhase")]
    public double MoonPhase { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipIntensity")]
    public double PrecipIntensity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipIntensityMax")]
    public double PrecipIntensityMax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipIntensityMaxTime")]
    public int PrecipIntensityMaxTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipProbability")]
    public double PrecipProbability { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("precipType")]
    public string PrecipType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperatureMin")]
    public double TemperatureMin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperatureMinTime")]
    public int TemperatureMinTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperatureMax")]
    public double TemperatureMax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temperatureMaxTime")]
    public int TemperatureMaxTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperatureMin")]
    public double ApparentTemperatureMin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperatureMinTime")]
    public int ApparentTemperatureMinTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperatureMax")]
    public double ApparentTemperatureMax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("apparentTemperatureMaxTime")]
    public int ApparentTemperatureMaxTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dewPoint")]
    public double DewPoint { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("humidity")]
    public double Humidity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windSpeed")]
    public double WindSpeed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("windBearing")]
    public int WindBearing { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cloudCover")]
    public double CloudCover { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pressure")]
    public double Pressure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ozone")]
    public double Ozone { get; set; }
}

public class Daily
{

    [JsonProperty("summary")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Datum2[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Flags
{

    [JsonProperty("sources")]
    public string[] Sources { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isd-stations")]
    public string[] IsdStations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("madis-stations")]
    public string[] MadisStations { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("units")]
    public string Units { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timezone")]
    public string Timezone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("offset")]
    public double Offset { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currently")]
    public Currently Currently { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hourly")]
    public Hourly Hourly { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("daily")]
    public Daily Daily { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("flags")]
    public Flags Flags { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this

```
 var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
```